# Unable to locate Radio Button in iFrame

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, iframe, radio-button

Trying to locate Radio Button inside iFrame but getting error as No Such Element found.

Tried switching to iFrame but still getting the same error. Not sure what am I missing. Tried couple of methods but did not get through. Not sure if my Xpath is wrong or way I use id to locate element is wrong. [Verified my Xpath in Developer tools but still getting the same error of No suh Element found]

Thank you in advance.

```
public class Sap_Demo {

    WebDriver driver;
    JavascriptExecutor jse;

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {

        Sap_Demo demoObj = new Sap_Demo();

        demoObj.invokeBrowser();
        demoObj.initializeSAPFiory();
        demoObj.forecastMD61();

    }



    public void invokeBrowser()
    {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "U:\\Research Paper\\Selenium\\Drivers\\Chrome\\chromedriver_win32\\chromedriver.exe");
        driver = new ChromeDriver();

        driver.manage().deleteAllCookies();
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(40, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        driver.manage().timeouts().pageLoadTimeout(40, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    }

    public void initializeSAPFiory()
    {

        try 
        {
            Thread.sleep(1200);
            driver.get("https://dijon.cob.csuchico.edu:8042/erp");
            driver.findElement(By.id("USERNAME_FIELD-inner")).sendKeys("H4");
            Thread.sleep(1200);

            driver.findElement(By.id("PASSWORD_FIELD-inner")).sendKeys("Onsjhjsa1087");
            Thread.sleep(1200);

            driver.findElement(By.id("CLIENT_FIELD-inner")).clear();
            Thread.sleep(1200);

            driver.findElement(By.id("CLIENT_FIELD-inner")).sendKeys("485");
            Thread.sleep(1200);

            driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[@class='sapMBtnContent sapMLabelBold sapUiSraDisplayBeforeLogin']")).click();
        } 
        catch (InterruptedException e) 
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void forecastMD61()
    {

        try {
            driver.findElement(By.id("erpsim-tcode-btn-img")).click();
            Thread.sleep(1200);

            driver.findElement(By.id("TCode-input-inner")).sendKeys("MD61");
            Thread.sleep(1200);

            driver.findElement(By.id("TCode-launchBtn-content")).click();
            Thread.sleep(1200);

            driver.switchTo().defaultContent();
            WebElement iframe = driver.findElement(By.id("ITSFRAME1"));
            driver.switchTo().frame(iframe);

            /*driver.switchTo().frame(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[@id='M0:46:::4:2-imgSymb']")));
            driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[@id='M0:46:::4:2-imgSymb']")).sendKeys("ABC");*/


            //driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(40, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
            //Thread.sleep(1600);


            /*driver.switchTo().frame("ITSFRAME1");
            WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
            wait.until(ExpectedConditions.frameToBeAvailableAndSwitchToIt("ITSFRAME1"));*/

            /*WebElement E1 = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.id("M0:46:::4:2-imgStd")));
            WebElement E1 = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[@id='M0:46:::4:2-imgSymb']"));
            E1.click();*/

            //driver.findElement(By.id("M0:46:::4:2-imgStd")).click();
            //driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[@id='M0:46:::4:2-imgStd']")).click();
            //Thread.sleep(1200);
        } 
        catch (InterruptedException e) 
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }


}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your first xpath for the element and the id for the iframe are correct, but as the window is getting opened in a new tab, you need to switch the driver to the new tab.
So, instead of using `driver.switchTo().defaultContent();`
You need to use:

```
ArrayList<String> tabs = new ArrayList<String> (driver.getWindowHandles());
driver.switchTo().window(tabs.get(1));
```

And if you want to switch to the original tab, you need to use:

```
driver.switchTo().window(tabs.get(0));
```

Comment: Facing Same error, when navigate to next page. Should I need to change any index?This is the code :

ArrayList<String> tabs = new ArrayList<String> (driver.getWindowHandles());
driver.switchTo().window(tabs.get(1));
driver.switchTo().frame("ITSFRAME1");
driver.findElement(By.id("M0:46:::4:2-imgStd")).click();
driver.findElement(By.id("M0:46:::4:26")).clear();
driver.findElement(By.id("M0:46:::4:26")).sendKeys("HH-F");
driver.findElement(By.id("M0:50::btn[0]")).click(); 
driver.findElement(By.id("tbl294940[1,8]_c-r")).sendKeys("800");

Comment: @SagarBhatt if the next page is on the same tab then you dont need to switch the driver position, if its opening on a new tab then you to switch the driver and send an index 2 in this case instead of 1.

Comment: Would you be able to see my another question accessing the text area please? 
Ques: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55466437/unable-to-locate-element-after-navigated-to-new-page

Comment: @SagarBhatt in your new answer, after just entering the values in "Product group" and clicking on Continue button, the page is throwing an error to enter all the fields? And you have mentioned to need to enter the values in "M 05-2019" but i cant see that field on the page

Comment: It may because, It was already opened in my machine. Would you please have a look again.I have closed all the instances opened my side. 
Request you please check.